# Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net, database-connection, connection-pooling

In our project user using NHibernate 2.1.1 with SQL Server 2008 with .net 3.5.

I am facing strange problem with SQL Server. We developed windows service, installed it and it was running fine for sometime. Unfortunately by mistake when I stopped SQL Server, NHibernate throw exception

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

But after restarting the SQL Server, it is unable to connect to the SQL Server, still throwing the same error. But I am able to connect SQL Server through Query Analyzer / Management Studio.

Please any body can help me in solving the problem?

Thanks

nRk

Comment: Are analyzer/studio also using the *named pipes provider?

Comment: NO. it's using default protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to \Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft SQL Server 2008\Configuration Tools, launch SQL Server Configuration Manager and enable the connection protocols you need.

Comment: All necessary protocols are enabled. But previously working fine, after restarting only it was giving problem... Why it was happend..?

Answer (score 1):

I know you already an answer but I got the same error but the solution was different, maybe this will help someone else.

When I was setting up ASP.Net to store the session variables in a DB I got the same error

> provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server

The cause of  my problem was the database couldn't be found on the SQL Server I was connecting to. Once I create the database correctly everything worked correctly.

Given the cause of the problem I would have expected the error message

> provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified

Answer (score 1):

I had to "Scroll to the bottom and set the TCP Port under IPAll, (1433 by default)" as mentioned in this answer

[How can I make MS SQL Server available for connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086764/how-can-i-make-ms-sql-server-available-for-connections)

Answer (score 0):

check the following
(a) First makesure that the Database Service of this instance is
running... use Configuration Manager
(b) if the service is running, check is this a named instance. in
that case is SQL Server Browser service running.
(c) Check Remote COnnection is enabled for Local and Remote
COnnection using TCP/IP -- use SQL Server Surface Area Configuration
Tool to view and configur
(d) Check all the protocols are enabled or not -- Use SQL
Configuration Manager -- SQL Server Network Configuration --
Protocol for MSSQLSERVER -- Enable TCP/IP and NamedPipe

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server Configuration Manager program, start SQL SERVER, enable the TCP/IP connection. If needed, allow the port in the firewall.