# ms sql configuration in beans.xml

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, struts

I've installed the MS SQL Server 2008 and I want to use it in a Java project with Struts.
Unfortunately I cannot configure it in Java. I am using the Windows authentication for MsSql. Is that possible?

My beans.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" 
  "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <!-- S2-Install-Start: INSERT DB SERVER HERE -->
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=MyDatabase" />
        S2-Install-End:
        <property name="username" value="Stefana\Steffi" />
        S2-Install-Start: INSERT DB PASSWORD HERE
        <property name="password" value="" />
        S2-Install-End:
    </bean>
```

I don't know what should I write in the user and password fields? When I connect to the Ms Sql Server, I get the following:

```
Servertype: DatabaseEngine

Servername: Stefana\SQLEXPRESS

Authentication: Windows Authentication

Username:Stefana\Steffi

Password:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows authentication if you use the [jTDS JDBC Driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) for SQL Server. The jTDS driver is free, open source and generally more powerful than the official Microsoft one.

If you include the jTDS jar in your project, I believe this datasource URL should work:

```
jdbc:jtds://localhost:1433/MyDatabase;domain=Stefana
```

Because you're running on Windows the jTDS driver is capable of using a native library to automatically log you in with your current credentials. However it's usually a better idea to explicitly specify the username and password, because that way your web app won't behave differently depending on who starts it up.

Note also that SQL Server 2008 probably won't have TCP connections enabled by default. Unless you turn that on you won't be able to connect with either the Microsoft driver or the jTDS one.

**To enable TCP connections:**

- Open *Sql Server Configuration Manager* (it should be on your Start menu)
- In the tree on the left, navigate to *SQL Server Network Configuration* then *Protocols for MSSQLSERVER*
- You should see *TCP/IP* in the list of protocols.
- If its status is *Disabled* then double-click it, and change the *Enabled* option to *Yes* and click *OK*
- You now need to restart SQL Server. Navigate to the *SQL Server Services* item
- Right-click on *SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)* in the list of services
- Choose *Restart*
- You should now be able to connect to SQL Server from your Java web app

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right thing to do.

Do you own that database?  Your config says "localhost", so I'll assume yes.  You should be using another username and password for your application from SQL Server, not Windows Authentication.  I'd create a separate user just for this application.  Give it access only to the application schema, and GRANT the minimum permissions necessary to accomplish its mission (e.g. no DELETE permission if not needed; no access to SYSTEM tables if not needed; no running stored procedures if not needed).

A better solution is to use a JNDI data source and not have passwords in plain text on your machine.

Comment: Yes, the database is on my localmachine ..I've read about the default username "sa", but know know the password of it, it is there a default password as well?

Comment: I've created a new user: stefi, with the password: stefi12345 .. but still doesn't work

Comment: That username doesn't look right to me; I don't see that password anywhere.  Your Spring config isn't correct.  I know it works; I use it every day.

Comment: I've got the following error in browser: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".

Comment: My beans.xml : <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <!-- S2-Install-Start: INSERT DB SERVER HERE -->
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:2996;DatabaseName=MyDatabase" />
        <!-- S2-Install-End: -->
        <property name="username" value="stefi" />
        <!-- S2-Install-Start: INSERT DB PASSWORD HERE -->
        <property name="password" value="stefi12345" />
        <!-- S2-Install-End: -->
    </bean>

Comment: I've tried this .. but still doesn't work [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086764/how-can-i-make-ms-sql-server-available-for-connections

Comment: Look at the exception - looks like there's no listener running on port 1433.  If you start up the SQL Server Studio, can you get into the database?  If not, Java won't be able to, either.  It's not a Spring problem.  It's more fundamental than that.

Answer (score 0):

replace the property:

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=MyDatabase" />
```

for:

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=MyDatabase;" />
```

Done!!!