# Generate db diagram from any sql statement

Tags: sql, ide, diagram, auto-generate, dbartisan

I'm using DBArtisan 8.5.5 and it has the ability to generate Database Diagrams using Build Query, it has a nice feature that lets it autojoin, detecting potential relationships on newly added tables to the diagram. So the diagram results into a SQL statement since its a Query Builder after all.

Is it possible to provide an SQL statement in DBArtisan and generate the Database Diagram? In other words, the reverse (give it the SQL to generate the diagram, instead of using diagrams to generate SQL)?

If no such feature, is there a product out there for Sybase DB that will provide said feature?

Comment: Power Designer is a powerful tool: http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/powerdesigner

Comment: Does it have the same feature as http://snowflakejoins.com/revj/index?

Comment: yes, it has the feature you are requiring

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate table relationship diagram from existing schema (SQL Server)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168724/generate-table-relationship-diagram-from-existing-schema-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

[DbVis](https://www.dbvis.com/) is an actionable choice, being open source and powerful - it's got a good amount of [extra features](https://www.dbvis.com/features/sybase-ase-database-features/) aside from the one you need.

If you're willing to pay, [Aqua Data Studio](https://www.aquafold.com/aquadatastudio) is a very complete and intuitive database IDE.

As a middle ground solution, disposing of both a - constantly updated - open source edition, the [DBeaver Open Source IDE](https://dbeaver.io/), and an [Enterprise Edition](https://dbeaver.com/). Both of these also offer what you need, the main differences as of now being interface, SSH algorithm support and SQL debugging framework offered in Enterprise. You can take a deeper look yourself, comparing the [Open Source features](https://dbeaver.io/docs/features/) with the [Enterprise ones](https://dbeaver.com/features/).